# C function to find the less program

Tags: c, posix

I've written a C function to find the program `less` that the operating system should provide. If `less`is not provided, some other pager variable should be used. I compile it with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -O3`.

```
int findless(char *less_token, int ret) {
    int breakloop = 0;
    char *new_str;
    while (less_token != NULL) {
        if ((new_str = malloc(strlen(less_token) + strlen("/less") + 1)) != NULL) {
            new_str[0] = '\0';
            strcat(new_str, less_token);
            strcat(new_str, "/less");
            if (file_exist(new_str)) {
                /* Found less */
                ret = 0;
                breakloop = 1;
            }
            free(new_str);
            if (breakloop) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            printf("malloc failed!\n");
        }
        less_token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Can you please review it? I put in in a separate utilities `util.c` file and I'm including it with a `util.h` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clearer Naming Needed**

In general, I think your variable naming could be better. I would rename `less_token` to be called `path` or something to make it clearer what you're doing here. `new_str` should be called `current_path` or `curr_path`. Moreover, I'd make the function name something more like `find_less_program`.

**C Style**

If you're going to be changing the `ret` parameter, it's idiomatic in C to pass in a pointer to `ret` and modify that. Either that or remove `ret` as a parameter and just return an `int` as an error code. Moreover, whenever I see a `break` in a `while` loop, I get a small frown on my face as that's usually a sign of bad control flow. See below for (IMO) a better control flow.

Moreover, it's been over a decade since C99 came out and introduced us to the `bool` type definitions. Prefer using them over the standard `int` way of signaling true or false. You'll need to include `stdbool.h` to use `bool`.

I would also create a small constant buffer containing the name of the program we're looking for (in this case `"/less"`.) This prevents you from having to write `"/less"` all over the place and instead just use a variable name. There's no need to assign the first character of the allocated buffer to `NULL` in this case. Just call `strcpy` to copy the string name into the buffer instead of relying on `strcat`. This also makes your intent clearer as you're first *copying* an existing string into a buffer and then *appending* to it.

Here's a possible implementation taking together all of the above suggestions:

```
bool find_less_program(char *path) {

    bool found = false;
    char *curr_path;
    const char program[] = "/less";

    while (path && !found) {
        if ((curr_path = malloc(strlen(path) + sizeof(program))) != NULL) {

            strcpy(curr_path, path);
            strcat(curr_path, program);
            if (file_exist(curr_path)) {
                found = true; // we found the program
            }
            free(curr_path);
            path = strtok(NULL, ":");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I compile it with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -O3` though that is not final. Maybe I can't use the `bool` type because I compile using an old standard (C90).

Comment: No problem. In that case, it's trivial to switch from `bool` to `int` and replace `true` with `1` and `false` with `0`. :)

Comment: Now I also think there could be a typo where you put `less_token` instead of `path` in the head of the while loop.

Comment: Oops! You're correct. I fixed it in the answer :)

Comment: Now I tested the code and it works perfectly.